# Captura de tecla

Tags: c, linux

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo da cobrinha em linguagem C (*gcc 4.9.2*) para o terminal do Ubuntu *15.04*.

Preciso capturar uma tecla digitada pelo usuário para que ele possa mudar a direção em que a *cobrinha* anda (`w`para cima, `s` para baixo, `a`para a esquerda, `d` para a direita).

Para isso, estou usando o seguinte trecho de código, dentro de uma laço de repetição que move a cobrinha automaticamente enquanto o usuário não muda a direção:

```
if(kbhit())
    seta = getchar();
```

`seta` é uma variável do tipo `char` que armazena a tecla digitada.

O programa faz a leitura corretamente, porém, ele também escreve na tela o caractere capturado, o que, obviamente, não pode acontecer em um jogo desse tipo.

Existem alguma função em C que captura a tecla sem escrever o caractere na tela ou qualquer procedimento equivalente?

**Obs**.: Embora `kbhit()` seja uma função originalmente da `conio.h`, consegui defini-la para Linux e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Implemente essa função feita pelo [`gdj`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734095/3257568):

```
#include <termios.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <errno.h>  
#define ECHOFLAGS (ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL)  
int set_disp_mode(int fd,int option)  
{  
   int err;  
   struct termios term;  
   if(tcgetattr(fd,&term)==-1){  
     perror("Cannot get the attribution of the terminal");  
     return 1;  
   }  
   if(option)  
        term.c_lflag|=ECHOFLAGS;  
   else  
        term.c_lflag &=~ECHOFLAGS;  
   err=tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,&term);  
   if(err==-1 && err==EINTR){  
        perror("Cannot set the attribution of the terminal");  
        return 1;  
   }  
   return 0;  
}
```

E depois na hora de chamar

```
while(1) {
    if (kbhit()) 
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        set_disp_mode(STDIN_FILENO,0); // 0 faz não exibir, se caso quiser voltar a exibir chame a função passando 1
        int c = getch();

        if (c == 65) // a
        { ...
```

Comment: @JoãoPedro Seria isso http://stackoverflow.com/a/7469410/3257568 ?

Comment: @JoãoPedro Como você implementou o kbhit?

Comment: Digo o código de dentro do kbhit, você disse que implementou, não?

Comment: @JoãoPedro Da uma olhada nessa função [`set_disp_mode`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9734095/3257568) implementa ela e chama ela com valor `0` antes do getchar()

Comment: @JoãoPedro Atualizei minha resposta

Comment: tu tem algum getchar antes do while?

Comment: Tranquilo então, fico feliz que resolveu :)

Comment: Se possível marque como a resposta certa, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para sistemas baseados no Unix, você poderá utilizar as funções do [cabeçalho `termios.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/termios.h.html) e [`fcntl.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/fcntl.h.html) para implementar as funções `kbhit` e `getch` do Windows.

Segundo essas páginas <sup>[`1`](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html)</sup> <sup>[`2`](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/148447/getch-implementation-in-unix)</sup>, isto pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int ch;
  int oldf;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

  ch = getchar();

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

  if(ch != EOF)
  {
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int getch(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}
```

Como alternativa, existe a [biblioteca `ncurses`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), que provê a [função `getch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch), *ainda* não sei se há suporte para a função `kbhit`. Para usá-la, é necessário incluir `curses.h`, se não estiver instalado, abra um terminal e digite:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

A função getch() captura do usuário sem mostrar na tela a resposta. Dá uma olhada no link do github:

https://github.com/CarlosAdir/C-Programs/tree/master/Tutoriais

Baixe toda a pasta e execute o arquivo 8-extras.c e veja como funciona. O arquivo kbhitgetch.pdf explica e tem uma boa base para entender como funciona por trás.